# Why does MySQL query return zero rows, but after defrag it works?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an InnoDB, MySQL table and this query returns zero rows:

```
SELECT id, display FROM ra_table WHERE parent_id=7266 AND display=1;
```

However, there are actually 17 rows that should match:

```
SELECT id, display FROM ra_itable1 WHERE parent_id=7266;

ID    display
------------------
1748  1
5645  1
...
```

There is an index on display (int 1), and ID is the primary key. The table also has several other fields which I'm not pulling in this query.

After noticing this query wasn't working, I defragmented the table and then the first query started working correctly, but only for a time. It seems after a few days, the query stops working again and I have to defragment to fix it.

My question is, why does the fragmented table break this query?

Additional info: MySQL 5.6.27 on Amazon RDS.

```
CREATE TABLE `ra_table` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`parent_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
`display` int(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
KEY `display` (`display`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13302 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Comment: And we know DIDELY-SQUAT about your tables design/System/etc. So are you hoping for a Clairvoyant to pass by and answer this

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 [and take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I guess my real question is, is this normal? Nothing I read online about fragmented MySQL tables states that they affect query results. Only that it takes up storage space...

Comment: @RiggsFolly, like I said, there's an index on display (which is INT1), ID is the primary key, the table is INNODB. Honestly I'm not sure what else might be relevant? The system is running on Amazon RDS, MySQL 5.6.27.

Comment: What version are you running?  What indexes exist on the table?  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

Comment: @RickJames, as I mentioned there are a number of fields here so I've tried to simplify the structure. Here's the SHOW result, but pared down to the relevant fields: CREATE TABLE `ra_table` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `parent_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
 `display` int(1) NOT NULL
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
 KEY `display` (`display`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13302 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC

Comment: What do you mean by "defragmented the table"? What specific steps did you take?

Comment: Why you used int(number) in your query it doesn't mean that your integer will be that long it's only the display width you can see it here https://alexander.kirk.at/2007/08/24/what-does-size-in-intsize-of-mysql-mean/      Try to use int only that may be the probable cause.

Comment: @duskwuff: I'm running ALTER TABLE  `ra_table` ENGINE = INNODB to defragment https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html

Comment: Since you're using Amazon RDS, a lot of the normal debugging options for MySQL won't be available. You should probably forward this question to Amazon technical support.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a bug in the version you are running.

Meanwhile, change

```
INDEX(parent_id),
INDEX(display)
```

to

```
INDEX(parent_id, display)
```

By combining them, the query will run faster (and hopefully correctly).  An index on a flag (`display`) is likely to never be used.